# SQL Database design to store items and grouping

Tags: sql, database-design

I would like to create a database to store items.
And would like to have a group to add and remove them from.
Is this the correct way or there is a better way where I am currently using this:

```
Item Table
itemid  itemname 
------  --------
1       Test1
2       Test2

Group Table
groupid  groupname  itemid
-------  ---------  ------
1        Group1     [1][2]  (this holds both items in the group)
2        Group2     [1]     (this holds item 1 only)
```

And how should the SQL statement be in my case to show when i search by Group1 to display the following

```
ItemID  Itemname  Group
------  --------  -----
1       Test1     Group1,Group2
```

And when i search for all item it should show

```
ItemID  Itemname  Group
------  --------  -----
1       Test1     Group1,Group2
2       Test2     Group1
```

Comment: Your `itemid` is a *Repeating Group*, which violates 1. NF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: This is about general database design & implementation, my advice is to read a good book about it, or go look for some online video tutorials. SO is not intended for explaining broad concepts or to replace a school or a class.

Comment: Thank you guys for the correction and pointers.

Comment: **Never** stored comma separated values in a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your database!  You should have a table called `GroupItems` with one row per item and per group.  It would look like:

```
GroupItemId   GroupId   ItemId
     1           1         1
     2           1         2
     3           2         1
```

Why is your structure wrong?

- Values should be stored using the correct type.  I interpret your list as a string, and the values as numbers.
- A column represents an *attribute* and should have only one value.
- SQL has poor string processing functions.
- Foreign keys should be properly defined.
- SQL cannot use indexes and other capabilities to optimize queries.